# How can I sniff the traffic used to set options on the router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, sniffing, man-in-the-middle

I'm sorry if this ends up being a duplicate; I have read a number of similar questions on here, but none seems to quite fit what I'm asking.

My broadband provider, Vodafone, gives my the ability to 'boost' one device at a time - for example, if I want to stream a movie on one device, I can boost it so that it receives a better connection.

I usually have a bit of trouble connecting my phone to the wireless network via the Vodafone Connect router, and I find that using the 'boost' feature normally helps.

The mobile app used to do the boosting is a bit annoying to use, and I'd also like to be able to automate the process, so I'm trying to work out which network packets I need to send to the router in order to boost one of my devices.

Unfortunately, I can only boost devices through the app on my phone (and not through the web interface on my computer), so it's more difficult than I'd like to sniff the network traffic between the two and filter out exactly those signals that are used for the boosting.

I've tried setting up a Man in the Middle attack between my phone and my router on my computer (running Arch Linux 4.19 LTS), but I'm not convinced that I'm picking up the packets that are to do with boosting the device.

Obviously, most of the signals between the phone and the router are related to the phone accessing the internet, rather than direct contact between the two, but I'm not sure if it's possible to filter these out without also filtering out the packets I'm interested in.

Comment: **This question needs more details.** Are you saying you don't have the bandwidth to stream anything unless you use the ISP smart phone app? What is the type of connection? What's the make model of the ISP gateway device? What Linux OS are you actually using? And last but not least, who is the ISP? **Please add this info to your question and not the comments section**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the best solution turned out to be to sniff the traffic directly through an app on the phone, rather than trying to do it through a computer.